How to separate the animation of a grease pencil object from the object movement
I am hoping to create a paper mario style look, buts its annoying to animate the drawings and move them through space in the same workspace. My goal is to have a 2d animation workspace of a grease pencil object that is always from the perspective of the object. Then I can go to the layout workspace and move many different of these objects through 3d space relative to each other and the camera. This way I can separate the animation of the grease pencil object from the movement of the object.
I have tried parenting each grease pencil object to a blank image, but this hasn't really helped.  I am new to blender and keep screwing up the stroke placement and drawing plane settings when trying to draw on a rotated or moving image.  It would be easier if I could always look at the image relative to the image, even if it is moving in 3d space, so I can animate the drawing on it while it moves in space.
Is there a way to do this?  Or a different way to solve this problem?

You can add a new camera, to be used for drawing only, and set it as child of the Grease Pencil object.
Set the camera as "Orthographic, drawing plane as "View" and an appropriate Stroke Placement.
Use  Ctrl  Numpad 0 to switch between cameras.

